# Docker container exits automatically with exit code 139

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

Docker container which runs a java program(spring) crashes intermittently and each time it crashes I go in the restart the container after removing the core.1 dump file generated within the container.
This happens in the production environment.

Tried multiple times to reproduce the same in a similar environment but no luck.

As a workaround , the container is set to restart automatically each time it stops.

```
docker update --restart=on-failure:3 <container_id>
```

Can we have the core dump written to a location outside the container when it fails?

```
Host System details :
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.5
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:5:server
            Kernel: Linux 4.1.12-124.18.6.el7uek.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-6



Inside Container :
 **cat /etc/os-release**

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Open JDK version inside the container :

```
**java -version**

    openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode
```

Please advice .
Thanks,
Albin

Comment: I believe that you can add the `-XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/dumps/mydump` when running the `java` command to specify the location of the crash dump file, and then mount a volume between your host and your container to access the crash log from your host : `docker run [...] -v /somewhere/on/your/host:/path/to/dumps <your_image>`. You should then have access to the crash dump from your host.